# jQuery Mobile Website - Hide Google Analytics Tracking Code

Tags: jquery, mobile, google-analytics

I've developed a mobile application with the "Mobilize" mobile website theme from Themeforest, which uses jQuery.  I have Google Analytics for Mobile Websites code inserted into each page I want to track, but the problem is that while each page loads, the code displays for a split second.  See below:

http://m.eyemagic.net

I've tried hiding the code, but no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see a thing. Where am I supposed to look?

Answer (score 0):

Why is the code in a `<div>` tag?

```
<div style="display:hidden;">
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
    //...
});
</div>
```

That's not going to work. Because first, it makes the code actual renderable text on the page, and second, it *will not actually execute*, so this code does nothing.

Put that code in a `<script>` tag instead to solve both of those issues.

Once your page's stylesheet loads, the actual page content gets positioned on top of this code div, obscuring it so it cant be seen.

Also, `display: hidden` is invalid CSS. You probably wanted `display: none`, which would have hid it and and removed it form the page flow. You probably confused that rule with `visibility: hidden` which would hide the elements but it would still take up space on the page.

But regardless, if that's actually a script tag, the styling doesn't matter at all.